# MySQL how to cascade on delete without foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Alright so first let me introduce my schema.

table: users

```
Field    |     Type    |  Key  |  NN   | AI
---------------------------------------------
id       | int(11)     | PRIM  |  YES  | YES
username | varchar(50) |       |  YES   | NO
banned   | int(1)      |       |  YES   | NO

Foreign keys: none
```

table: macs

```
Field    |     Type    |  Key  |  NN   | AI
---------------------------------------------
id       | int(11)     | PRIM  |  YES  | YES
address  | varchar(50) |       |  YES   | NO
lastacc  | timestamp   |       |  YES   | NO

Foreign keys: none
```

table: usermac

```
Field    |     Type    |  Key  |  NN   | AI
---------------------------------------------
userId   | int(11)     | PRIM  |  YES  | NO
macId    | int(11)     |       |  YES  | NO


Foreign keys:
[FK: macId] references macId to id in table macs
[FK: userId] references userId to id in table users
```

The scenario is, I have a userId and wish to delete all records in macs that are linked to that userId (as stated by records in usermac)

The relation between users and macs: a user can have multiple macs and a mac can belong to multiple users.

What SQL query should I perform for this? I tried cascading delete but cascading does not work.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM mac WHERE id in (SELECT macId from usermac WHERE userId = <userId of deleted User>);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is the one, When I executed this in Mysql workbench it said something about safe mode preventing it but I turned that off and it worked. Will this safe mode error occur if I execute this query with JDBC in Java or is this error specific to Mysql workbench?

Comment: Can you post how did you turn off safe mode?

Comment: Okay as it has been turn off from MySQL. JDBC should't have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler the better:

```
DELETE FROM usermac WHERE userId=1;
```

will delete all macs for user 1

Comment: I have tried this and the records in usermac get deleted however the records in mac that were linked remain.

Comment: Yes, as you say they may belong to other users too

Comment: Thanks but I need to remove them regardless.

Comment: Then use the other answer. Nut I think it's better idea to remove everything needed from usermac and then to remove only these records from mac, which have not corresponding record in usermac, i.e. are orphans